# AWS role to grant access to use AWS resources by local spinnaker instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, roles, spinnaker

I am trying to setup spinnaker locally to manage AWS EC2 instances. The current documentaion depicts the steps which need to have spinnaker instance to be running on EC2. They are creating one role and attaching it to spinnaker [instance](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/providers/aws/#option-1-add-an-iam-role-to-the-spinnaker-ec2-instance). As I am running spinnaker in my local environment, I am finding a way which will allow my local spinnaker instance to access the AWS resources. Will it be possible to have one such policy/role ? May be using AWS-STS ( Security Toke Service ), but i dont know how to use that creds with spinnaker instance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly by creating an IAM user with required policies to access AWS Resources and use the **Programmatic access** Credentials in your local machine to use AWS CLI, API or SDKs.

For an existing IAM User, the step are as follows.

***IAM User -> Security Credentials -> Create Access Keys***

Note: If you cannot trust your local environment, then you can use AWS STS service (For this you need to implement a separate service, where you can pass user credentials and request for a temporal token from AWS STS)

Comment: I will get temporary creds from STS service, but how to use that in spinnaker instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the IAM role for your local machine to assume, like
[this example](https://github.com/Armory/spinnaker-aws-policy/blob/master/policies/SpinnakerInstanceProfile.clouddriver.v1.516.0.json), or stricter,
spinnaker will handle the STS assume role given its configured properly

as for the temporary credential, if what you mean is MFA compatibility, I am myself still figuring out the way to do it. I think one workaround is to create a wrapper script that call sts:assumeRole, ask the user to provide the MFA token, then set AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN which will be honored by clouddriver, but then deployment to multiple AWS accounts will be a problem